# Как расставить знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

"Без рук без топорёнка построена избёнка что это да это птичье гнездо вот сорочьё гнездо оно без сучьев сложено пол глиной вымазан крыша из веток сложена чем не избёнка."

Answer (score 1):

Без рук, без топорёнка построена избёнка. Что это? Да это птичье гнездо! Вот сорочье гнездо - оно без сучьев сложено, пол глиной вымазан, крыша из веток сложена. Чем не избёнка? Можно такой вариант. Только меня почему-то тире смущает.

Answer (score 1):

***Без рук, без топорёнка построена избёнка. Что это? Да, это птичье гнездо! Вот сорочье гнездо: оно без сучьев сложено, пол глиной вымазан, крыша из веток сложена - чем не избёнка?***

**Запятая** после "да" нужна, если на вопрос получен правильный ответ и"да" в этом случае является словом - предложением. Если же не ставить запятую, "да" окажется обычной частицей, интонация тоже изменится. Оба варианта вполне приемлемы.
**Двоеточие** ставим, так как второе предложение в БСП поясняет первое, раскрывает его содержание.
**Тире** перед третьей частью БСП ставим, так как третье простое предложение "чем не избёнка" имеет значение следствия (ср.: *так что чем не избёнка?*)

Answer (score 0):

Без рук, без топорёнка построена избёнка. Что это? Да это птичье гнездо, вот сорочьё гнездо - оно без сучьев сложено, пол глиной вымазан, крыша из веток сложена, - чем не избёнка?

Comment: Гнезда все-таки сорОчье, а не сорочьЁ.

Answer (score 0):

Вспоминается Гоголь: если бы к носу Ивана Ивановича приставить уши Ивана Никифоровича... Ни один из предложенных вариантов не кажется бесспорным. А может, так?
"Без рук, без топорёнка построена избёнка. Что это? Да это птичье гнездо! Вот сорочье гнездо: оно без сучьев сложено, пол глиной вымазан, крыша из веток сложена. Чем не избёнка!